# Remove controls on Grid based on Datatable value

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable

I have a MySQL Datatable with 3 columns : Name, X, Y

Let's say for now there's these values :
[image]

Basically I have a timer which loops through this Datatable and adds a new Button with Name, X, Y as it's location.

If I add a new row in my datatable, a new button will be created in the next timer's Tick event. Now how can I implement something to remove a button on the form which is not in the database anymore ?

Comment: You should add some of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember the list of buttons placed on the form. Then compare the list from the database and the list of buttons placed with `Except`.

Something like that:

```
IEnumerable<string> formButtons = ...;
IEnumerable<string> dbButtons = ...;
IEnumerable<string> buttonsToRemove = formButtons.Except(dbButtons);
```

`buttonsToRemove` now contains the buttons which are on the form, but not in the database anymore.